# Home and End keys in Emacs don't work when run from Tmux

Tags: terminal, emacs, tmux, xterm

When I run Emacs from Tmux, the `Home` and `End` keys do not work (`Home` key runs the Search command as if `C-s` was pressed). The problem started when I added this in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
TERM="xterm"
export TERM
```

I've read somewhere that TERM variable should not be set manually but this was the only way I was able to solve problems with colors. Without this setting I got different colors in Emacs when running directly from the terminal and different when running from Tmux. This option caused some of the keys not to work in Emacs when it was run from Tmux, so I added this line to my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

This solved problem with all keys except for `Home` and `End`. Any ideas how to make these keys work again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can think of *tmux* as a terminal emulator that provides a terminal that uses `screen`-based protocol (on the “inside”) which it translates into some other terminal protocol (on the “outside”) while providing features like panes, windows, sessions, a status bar, et cetera.

Since *tmux* always provides a `screen`-like terminal protocol on the “inside”, you must always use a `screen`-based TERM value inside *tmux*. Additionally, you must use an appropriate TERM value “outside” so that *tmux* knows how to talk to the terminal in which it is running (usually this is your terminal emulator, so use whatever terminal protocol your terminal emulator is configured to supply; often a variant of `xterm`).

Specifically, the problem you are facing is that a `screen` <kbd>Home</kbd> is `ESC [ 1 ~`, while it is `ESC O H` in `xterm`:

```
% tput -T screen khome | xxd
0000000: 1b5b 317e                                .[1~
% tput -T xterm khome | xxd
0000000: 1b4f 48                                  .OH
```

So, when *tmux* gets a <kbd>Home</kbd> from your terminal emulator (by decoding whatever is in `khome` of the TERM in effect when you attached to the *tmux* session), it sends the `screen`-Home `ESC [ 1 ~` (because *tmux* always uses a `screen` protocol on the “inside”), but the program (e.g. Emacs) is expecting the `xterm`-Home `ESC O H` (because you told it to expect the `xterm` values by setting `TERM=xterm`).

---

I am not sure what color problems you were having that caused you to try to switch to `TERM=xterm` inside *tmux*, but you should probably try making sure you refer to a color-supporting terminfo entry in your TERM values both “inside” and “outside” *tmux*: e.g. configure your terminal emulator to set TERM to `xterm-color`, `xterm-16color`, `xterm-88color`, or `xterm-256color` as appropriate; and use `set-option -g default-terminal screen-256color` in your *tmux* configuration (or `screen-16color`).

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was very confused on how Tmux handles `TERM` variable. Now it's a bit more clear.

Comment: I was too quick to say I understand how `TERM` works. I reverted everything to its original state (no explicit setting of `TERM` variable) and while `HOME` and `END` work correctly, the Ctrl+(Up/Down/Left/Right)Arrow within Emacs stopped working.

Comment: Modified arrow keys are an extension beyond the keys supported by terminfo; applications that read just the terminfo entry will not know about them. Individual applications must be taught how to recognize these modified keys. Emacs does this for `xterm`-based TERMs via its `…/term/xterm.el`, but `screen`-based TERMs are not handled. You might do something similar to what I have outlined [this Gist (linked)](https://gist.github.com/03101250a0c5bcc05f00).

Comment: I managed to get C-Up and similar running by using xterm-extras package for Emacs, but I guess I like your solution better cause I understand what it does :)